# Laravel 5.2 with PostgreSQL autoincrement not working, id must be filled

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, laravel-5

I am working on [Laravel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laravel) 5.2 with PostgreSQL now, and when insertion I have an error:

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 713:
  SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
  DETAIL: Failing row contains (null, null, t, 11, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 5, null, null, 1, null, 1, null, null, null, 1, null, 1, null, null, null, bla bla bakar bakar, null, null, 00000000469, 33, bla bladfs, TEST KEDUAAAA, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 45, 1, null, null, null). (SQL: insert into "produk_m" ("statusenabled", "kdproduk", "namaproduk", "kodeexternal", "kdproduk_intern", "objectdetailjenisprodukfk", "objectkategoryprodukfk", "objectgolonganprodukfk", "objectstatusprodukfk", "objectsatuankecilfk", "qtysatukemasan", "qtyterkecil", "kekuatan", "deskripsiproduk") values (1, 00000000469, TEST KEDUAAAA, 11, 33, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 45, 1, bla bladfs, bla bla bakar bakar) returning "id")
```

I must fill the id value; autoincrement is not working,

My model is like this:

```
<?php
    namespace App\Master;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Produk extends Model
    {
        protected $table ="produk_m";
        protected $fillable = ['statusenabled','kdproduk','namaproduk','kodeexternal', 'kdproduk_intern','objectdetailjenisprodukfk','objectkategoryprodukfk','objectgolonganprodukfk','objectstatusprodukfk','objectstatusprodukfk','objectsatuankecilfk','qtysatukemasan','qtyterkecil','kekuatan','deskripsiproduk'];
        public $timestamps = false;
        protected $primaryKey = 'id';
        // protected $guarded = array('id');
        public $incrementing = true;
    }
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Please add your migration

Comment: im not using migration, and in postgree database, :id is not auto increment